# External file field not working & throws null pointer exception

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I configured my external file field configuration like follows:

```
    < field name="idRank" type="idRankFile" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" valType="pfloat" />

    < fieldType name="idRankFile" keyField="id" defVal="10" stored="true" indexed="true" class="solr.ExternalFileField" valType="pfloat|float|tfloat" />
```

Following are the value I kept in the file named :external_idRank.txt.Here keys are the values of size field in the document.

```
2938025 = 100.0 

4030380 = 115.0

9751 = 125.0

12738 = 135.0 

9752 = 145.0
```

I used the following query to retrieve the result, sorting it based on the `idRank` value:

```
/solr/collection1/select/?&q=content:* _ val _:"sum(idRank,1)"&fl=size&rows=100
```

But, when I used the following query it throws Exception like follows,

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.solr.search.function.FileFloatSource.getFloats(FileFloatSource.java:273)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.function.FileFloatSource.access$000(FileFloatSource.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.function.FileFloatSource$2.createValue(FileFloatSource.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.function.FileFloatSource$Cache.get(FileFloatSource.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.function.FileFloatSource.getCachedFloats(FileFloatSource.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.function.FileFloatSource.getValues(FileFloatSource.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.queries.function.valuesource.MultiFloatFunction.getValues(MultiFloatFunction.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.queries.function.FunctionQuery$AllScorer.(FunctionQuery.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.queries.function.FunctionQuery$FunctionWeight.scorer(FunctionQuery.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:323)
>     at

What should I make to execute this query without exception?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your file content being:

```
2938025 = 100.0

4030380 = 115.0

9751 = 125.0

12738 = 135.0

9752 = 145.0
```

try keeping your file exactly as specified in https://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html i.e. like:

```
2938025=100.0
4030380=115.0
9751=125.0
12738=135.0
9752=145.0
```

Also try changing your fieldType definition to:

`<fieldType name="idRankFile" keyField="id" defVal="10" class="solr.ExternalFileField" valType="float" />`

Note that `indexed` and `stored` don't make sense for external file fields.